# Multiple foreign keys in hasMany relationship causing troubles with extra where clause

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Say you have a team, and a matches table. The team has multiple matches, with a foreign key on visitant_id or local_id (see also https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1272 )

In team model:

```
public function allMatches()
{
     return $this->hasMany('Match', 'visitant_id')->orWhere('local_id', $this->id);
}
```

This works fine like this:

```
$team = Team::find(2);
$matches = $team->all_matches;
```

Results in this query:

```
 select *
 from `matches` 
 where `matches`.`visitant_id` = ? 
 or `local_id` = ?
```

However, when expanding with an extra where clause, for example:

```
$matches = $team->all_matches->where('type','=',1);
```

The query becomes

```
 select * 
 from `matches` 
 where `matches`.`visitant_id` = ? 
 or `local_id` = ? and 'type' = ?
```

Which means it selects ALL visitor matches, even if the type is incorrect, because there's no ( ) around that clause. Any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameter grouping. It is described here http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#advanced-wheres

Comment: And how? The first where is made inside the relation you can't just pop that inside a closure...

Comment: That doesn't work for my problem case, because either I use advanced querying and it doesn't return a relationship anymore, or like @lukasgeiter says the closure would have to be inside the relationship, which is something I don't want.